# How and why do PDF renderers replace chars

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, adobe-acrobat, postscript

If you take a look at https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/font/pdfs/5176.CFF.pdf at page 6 the second point is called `Predefined Encodings 37` but the postscript for this sentence reads:

```
BT
/F4 1 Tf
9.5 0 0 9.5 210 664.663 Tm
(Appendix B) Tj
1.2632 -1.3158 TD
-0.0002 Tc
-0.0021 Tw
(PredeÞned Encodings) Tj
ET
```

Why is "fi" replaced with [þ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorn_(letter))?

Comment: That is not the binary data that I see in the PDF file you linked to. Where did you get that text from? What application? Did you process the PDF somehow?

Comment: mea culpa, I linked to the wrong version of the document.
http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/0/1/801a191c-029d-4af3-9642-555f6fe514ee/cff.pdf 

To answer your question, I use ```PdfSharp.Pdf.Content.ContentReader.ReadContent(page)``` to read the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source PDF: http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/0/1/801a191c-029d-4af3-9642-555f6fe514ee/cff.pdf

The actual character code used is 0xDE in the compressed content stream. How that appears in your text editor of choice can vary.

```
BT
/F4 1 Tf
9.5 0 0 9.5 210 664.663 Tm
(Appendix B)Tj
1.2632 -1.3158 TD
-0.0002 Tc
-0.0021 Tw
(PredeÞned Encodings)Tj
ET
```

We have a Character Code, now what is the font? `/F4` takes us to `Obj 4322`, which is a non-embedded simple font (single byte encoding), with `MacRomanEncoding`.

This encoding is defined in the PDF standard, in the Appendix `Latin character set and encodings`.

Note these values are in Octal, so `0xDE` becomes `o336` and looking under the MAC column we find that it is the ligature "fi" `U+FB01`.

> Why is "fi" replaced with þ?

It is not, the "þ" is actual the Octal character code `o336` which combined with the PDF MacRomanEncoding is the ligature "fi". If you had a text editor that supported PDF MacRomanEncoding you would see the ligature.